# Connect Logstash with RethinkDB on IBM BlueMix

Tags: logstash, ibm-cloud, rethinkdb

I try and connect Logstash with RethinkDB on IBM BlueMix. I have provisioned the RethinkDB-Service from BlueMix (with is from Compose I believe) and also provisioned a Virtual Machine (CentOS). Then I installed Logstash (using the yum package) and the plugin from here (https://github.com/wayann/logstash-input-rethinker). So far so good. Now I struggle to get a connection from Logstash to RethinkDB. I have sent host and port and auth_key in a similar config file (https://github.com/wayann/logstash-input-rethinker/blob/master/rethinker.conf) and started Logstash with `bin/logstash -f rethinker.conf` However, Logstash is unable to connect to RethinkDB. Has anyone experience using Logstash with RethinkDB on Bluemix? I have sent host and port according to the credentials available on the BlueMix dashboard (same as the admin UI) but I'm unsure what to use for `auth_key`. admin-password didn't work. BlueMix runs RethinkDB version 2.3.5

Any hint highly apprechiated

#### Edit1, Error message:

```
05:46:12.049 [[main]<rethinker] ERROR logstash.pipeline - A plugin 
had an unrecoverable error. Will restart this plugin.
 Plugin: <LogStash::Inputs::Rethinker host=>"sl-eu-lon-2-
portal.3.dblayer.com", port=>15216, auth_key=>"********", 
watch_dbs=>["test", "MyDB"], watch_tables=>["MyTable"], 
backfill=>"true", id=>"f1c07e0332787a22600c0835d2aa6ad61ca9b22b-1", 
enable_metric=>true, codec=><LogStash::Codecs::JSONLines 
id=>"json_lines_e24c0744-3983-4001-9629-d93e266c5ffb", 
enable_metric=>true, charset=>"UTF-8", delimiter=>"\n">, 
squash=>true, user=>"admin">
 Error: Connection closed by server.
```

#### Edit2, config file:

```
input { 
  rethinker {
    host => 'sl-eu-lon-2-portal.3.dblayer.com'
    port => 15216
    auth_key => '*****'
    watch_dbs => ['test','MyDB']
    watch_tables => ['MyTable']
    backfill => true
  }
}

output { 
  stdout { 
    codec => json_lines 
  } 
}
```

#### Edit3:

Ok, it was my error. I need to use the 'username', 'password' and 'ca_cert' parameters and not 'auth_key'. Using this configuration connects to the rethinkdb instance:

```
input { 
  rethinker {
    host => 'sl-eu-lon-2-portal.3.dblayer.com'
    port => 15216
    watch_dbs => ['MyDB']
    watch_tables => ['MyTable']
    backfill => true
    user => 'admin'
    password => '******'
    ca_certs => '<<cert-string>>'
  }
}

output { 
  stdout { 
    codec => json_lines 
  } 
}
```

Now, however, I get the following error:

```
03:54:37.252 [[main]<rethinker] ERROR logstash.pipeline - A plugin 
had an unrecoverable error. Will restart this plugin.
  Plugin: <LogStash::Inputs::Rethinker host=>"sl-eu-lon-2-
portal.3.dblayer.com", port=>15216, watch_dbs=>["MyDB"], 
watch_tables=>["MyTable"], backfill=>"true", user=>"admin", 
password=>"*****", ca_certs=>"**cert-string**", 
id=>"46aa34ee0917060057d4e9a0c657ee327df730ee-1", 
enable_metric=>true, codec=><LogStash::Codecs::JSONLines 
id=>"json_lines_c43cdbc3-1646-4e96-aadc-834e727949a6", 
enable_metric=>true, charset=>"UTF-8", delimiter=>"\n">, 
squash=>true>
  Error: No message available
```

How would I resolved this `Error: No message available` error? Logstash version is 5.5.2

Comment: Do you have an error message to share?

Comment: Yes, I have added it as Edit1. Forgot about that earlier :blush:

Comment: Could you also post your actual logstash config file?

Comment: Sure, see edit2

Comment: OK so, your error is `connection closed by server`. This means that you are actually connecting to a third party which is responding but rejecting your connection. It looks like an high level error, such as an authentication or authorization error. Do you have any log access on the rethinkdb side? I'd expect to get the cause of the problem there.

Comment: Not sure if I can look at the RethinkDB log. But I'll try. Thanks for the hint.

Comment: Do you have data in your db? Did you double check database and table names?

Comment: Yes, there is data in the DB. And the table names are correct

Comment: got it. The last missing piece was that I entered the whole cert-string in the config file and not the path to the actual cert file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally figured it out, thanks a lot for your help [@whites11](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1078969/whites11).

I needed to set the correct settings in the configuration file. That includes **user**, **password** and **ca-cert**. For **ca-cert** it is important that this is the path to the certificate file and **not** the certificate content as a string.

My setting looks like this now:

```
input { 
  rethinker {
    host => 'sl-eu-lon-2-portal.3.dblayer.com'
    port => 15216
    watch_dbs => ['MyDB']
    watch_tables => ['MyTable']
    backfill => true
    user => 'admin'
    password => '******'
    ca_certs => '<<path-to-cert-file>>'
  }
}

output { 
  stdout { 
    codec => json_lines 
  } 
}
```

Comment: you can accept your own answer if that's what worked for you.